# Kendo UI Combo Box -- How can I resize the suggest pane so I get rid of the X scroll bar

Tags: html, combobox, kendo-ui, kendo-combobox

Kendo UI Combo Box -- How can I modify the CSS to resize the suggest pane so I get rid of the X scroll bar and just fit the content?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To make it automatically fit the longest item you should add the following:

```
var dropdownlist = $("#dropdownlist").data("kendoDropDownList");
dropdownlist.list.width("auto");
```